# Example in $\mathbb R^3$ of the differential of a function as a dual vector

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, vector-spaces, tensor-products

To get an intuitive grasp on how the elements of the dual vector space can be seen as the differential forms of a function $f$, I'd like to have an example in Euclidean 3D $(x, y, z$ coordinates) of such function $f,$ showing how "feeding" a vector (understood as partial derivatives of the function), and with the component selection role of $\delta^i_j,$ a vector in the dual ends up producing a scalar.

Comment: I already suggested this to you, but you probably will find [my lectures](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCp9W-et2Zbx7u5_VMiXGtPQ/videos) helpful, starting with MATH 3510 Lecture 24 (see the complete version at the very top of the list), and continuing as far as you want.